# Dimension of dominant morphism of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

In differential geometry, there exists an immersion of a curve into a sphere whose image is dense. I wanted to know if this paradox still exists in algebraic geometry. I think the answer should be no.

Let $A \rightarrow B$ be an injective homomorphism of rings of finite type. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are Noetherian domains. Is it true that
$$ \mathrm{dim}\,A \leq \mathrm{dim}\,B \quad ?$$

I made a bit of progress.

If $A$ and $B$ are finite type $k$-algebras then the statement is true. In this case, the injection $A \rightarrow B$ gives an injection of their fields of fractions $R(A) \rightarrow R(B)$. But then $\mathrm{dim}\,A = \mathrm{tr\,deg}_k R(A)$, $\mathrm{dim}\,B = \mathrm{tr\,deg}_k R(A)$ and $\mathrm{tr\,deg}_k R(B) \leq \mathrm{tr\,deg}_k R(B)$.

If the corresponding morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\, B \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, A$ is closed then the statement follows from [Lemma 02JX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JX). This makes me think that there may be an issue if the map is not closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "rings of finite type"?

Comment: I mean that $B$ is of finite type over $A$, so there is a surjection $A[x_1,...,x_r] \rightarrow B$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What if $A$ is a DVR with uniformiser $\pi$ and $B = K = A[t]/(t\pi-1)$ its fraction field?

Comment: As stated, no. You could have $A$ a discrete valuation ring (dimension $1$) and $B$ its field of fractions (dimension $0$).

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you both